# argument labels "mkcoordinate" do not match any available overloads swift 4

Tags: swift, mapkit

The code I am using is from xcode 8 swift 3. I want to know what I should do to convert this to xcode 9 swift 4.

```
func openInMaps(sender: UIButton) {
    for i in 0...2
    {
    let coordinate = coordinates[i]
    let latitude = coordinate[0]
    let longitude = coordinate[1]
    let coordinates1 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)

    let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 1000;
    let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates1, regionDistance, regionDistance)
```

The first line is where the error occur

```
    let options = [MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(mkcoordinate: regionSpan.center), MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(mkcoordinatespan: regionSpan.span)]

    let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates1)
    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    mapItem.name = "destination"
    mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: options)
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is not related to xcode, instead indicate base version of the Swift and the version which you use currently

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix a *do not match any available overloads* error is to use code completion.

- (Re)type <kbd>NSValue(</kbd>

You will see (hint: case sensitivity matters):

[image]

Alternatively [open the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsvalue) and look up the correct spelling of the initializers.